# Randomly Assigning ID Tags to different Sections in R

Tags: r, random

I am having trouble randomly assigning ID Tags to a Section. I generated a random string of 347 made up three-letter ID Tags (i.e., sbn, hjk, cvl). I would like each individual ID Tag to be randomly assigned to a Section (i.e., w,v,g,b). There are a total of 47 Sections. After assigning the ID Tags to one Section, I would very much like to create a data frame. Below is what I have so far:

```
##################### Create the ID Tags

random.tags <- function(n=347, length=3){
  randomString <- c(1:n)                  
  for (i in 1:n){
     randomString[i] <- paste(sample(c(letters, letters), length, replace=TRUE), collapse="")
  }
  return(randomString)
}

Tags<-random.tags()

################################# Create the Sections 

Sections<-c("w","v","u","t","s","r","q","p","o","n","m","l","k","j","i","g","f","e","d","c","b","a","aa","bb","cc","dd","ee","ff","gg","hh","ii","jj","kk","ll","mm",
             "nn","oo","pp","qq","rr","ss","tt","uu","vv","ww","xx","yy")
```

I thought using the sample function in R would allow me to randomly assign the ID Tags to one Section but I am not able to because the rows are different lengths.

```
  df <- data.frame(Tag=sample(Tags, replace=TRUE),
             Section=sample(Sections, replace=TRUE))  # doesn't work
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: `data.frame` won't form when the length of your `Tags` and `Sections` are not the same.

Comment: Hi, Adam. I am aware but is it possible to have the ID Tags (Individuals) select a Section? The 'Sections' are basically choices.

Comment: You just have to force one of the string to be the same as the other. E.g. `Sections <- c(Sections, rep(NA, 347-47)); df <- data.frame(Tags = sample(Tags, replace = FALSE), Section = sample(Sections, replace=FALSE)`

Comment: Thank you, Adam. This is almost it which is to randomly assign the ID Tags (individuals) to one OR multiple Sections. Each ID Tag needs to select one or several 'Sections'. Is there a way to not have any NAs? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: `df <- data.frame(Tags = Tags, Sections = samples(x = Sections, size = length(Tags), replace=TRUE)` ? BTW, I still don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am really sorry if I am not making myself clear. All I want to do is generate random data where I have let's say 347 individuals (i.e., ID Tags) and I want them to be randomly assigned to one location (i.e., Sections) out of 47 possibilities (like a random draw).  In the end, I want to end up with a data frame having one column of all the individuals and another column is the random location they were assigned in the simulation.

Comment: Bingo. This is it. Thank you very much, Adam. I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments:

```
df <- data.frame(individuals = 1:347)

locations <- replicate(47, paste(sample(c(letters, letters), 3, replace=TRUE), collapse=""))

df$location <- sample(locations, 347, replace = TRUE)
```